# Create txt based on a list of files names

Tags: batch-file, command

Here's my problem:
I have more than one thousand files inside a directory, and I want to make txt files with the name of each of them with the same text in this txt file.

For example:

> file1.zip file1.txt file2.zip file2.txt etc...

In the txt files, we can find the same text, previously defined. For example:

```
video_shader_enable = "true"
input_overlay_hide_in_menu = "false"
xmb_alpha_factor = "39"
menu_shader_pipeline = "0"
custom_viewport_width = "1161"
custom_viewport_height = "981"
custom_viewport_x = "205"
custom_viewport_y = "28"
aspect_ratio_index = "22"
input_overlay_opacity = "0.930000"
```

I need a command or script to do it by batch mode.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to describe.

Comment: I wanna avoid to make manually the same txt, thousand times, only with differents names...

Comment: Your existing files are all .ZIP?

Comment: yeah share the same extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the text file once. Name it for example `template.txt`. Then use a `for` loop to do something for each `.zip` file. For each file, copy `template.txt` to "filename" with extension `.txt` (`%~na` gives just the name without extension):

```
for %a in (*.zip) do copy "template.txt" "%~na.txt"
```

Note: this is command line syntax. If you want to use it in a batch file, use `%%a` and `%%~na`